# IdentityServer4: Add Custom default Claim to Client Principal for Client_Credential Granttype

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am using IdentityServer4 and I am trying to add a custom default claim to my `CLIENT` when the token is created. This is possible if i use the implicit flow and `IProfileService` like shown below.

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public MyProfileService()
    {

    }
    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("DemoClaimType", "DemoClaimValue")
        };
        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        context.IsActive = true;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

And in my startup

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddProfileService<MyProfileService>()
```

However this does not work with my client with client_credential granttype since it seems `cannot request OpenID scopes in client credentials flow`. It turns out Iprofileservice like the name implies works for `Identity` Resources where the OpenId scopes like profile is valid. since am unable to request profile scopes with client_credential grant type `GetProfileDataAsync` never gets called.

Since am working only with clients and no users I need a way to inject claims into the token without having to add them to the client object like below

```
    new Client
{
    ClientId = "myclient",
    ClientName = "My Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    ClientSecrets = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
    AllowedScopes = new List<string> {"api"},                    
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,

    //I Don't want to do this
    Claims = new List<Claim>
    {   
        new Claim("type","value")
    }
}
```

I do not want the above because i do not want the the claim to be part of the client_claims in the database. I need to create it on the fly on token request. I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: The `IProfileService` get's called when an `access_token` is being generated - it's used to add claims to it.

Comment: Also we're adding the `IProfileService` like this: `services.AddTransient<IProfileService, MyProfileService>();` (inside Startup > ConfigureServices) maybe that's your problem?

Comment: `AddProfileService` is the correct method.

Comment: @moritzg What i want is to Add to the default client claims (like for example there exists `client_id` which is not in the claims list for the client) using the Iprofileservice.

Comment: @Mardoxx The constructor is getting called but GetProfileDataAsync method is not getting called.

Comment: Maybe i should be implementing the IClaimsService rather than IProfileService? I realise that the Default Claims class uses this interface.

Comment: I think, not 100% sure, you need to either call userinfo endpoint (configure OIDC client to do this if you are using one) or set client's `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true`

Comment: @Mardoxx But that deals with `User` information. I am working with only clients

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With some investigation I finally found out how to do this. I needed a way to add claims dynamically to the client when token was requested.

In order to do that I had to extend `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` and then include my class in Startup.cs thorough dependency injection

```
public class DefaultClientClaimsAdder : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Client.AlwaysSendClientClaims = true;
        context.Result.ValidatedRequest.ClientClaims.Add(new Claim("testtoken","testbody"));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Configure services in Startup.cs

```
 services.AddTransient<ICustomTokenRequestValidator, DefaultClientClaimsAdder>();
```

Comment: Worth noted: with the latest version in IDS4 branch v1.x I had to use `context.Result.ValidatedRequest.ClientClaims` instead, else wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use `ClientStore` to add new claims into clients.

```
public class YourClientStore : IClientStore
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public YourClientStore(DbContext context,
        IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context= context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
    {
        var dbClient = _context.Clients.AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        var client = _mapper.Map<Client>(dbClient);
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Claims.Add(new Claim("<your claim name>", "<your claim value>"));
        }
        return Task.FromResult(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the DbContext of type `ConfigurationDbContext` which is provided by IdentityServer, and then in my configuration of IdentityServer (after `AddConfigurationStore`) I added the line `.AddClientStore<CustomClientStore>()` to enable the custom store.