# Multi-organization solution with identityserver4

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid, claims-based-identity

I've got following setup:

- IdentityServer4 using asp.net core identity
- Accounts app - where user can edit his account data and users can register
- Portal - where users can login and select an organization to which they're connected (same as in azure devops)
- API that is used by portal

Does anyone have experience setting up something similar ? My question would be how to authorize the calls at API level to make sure he is only editing entities that belong to his organization.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to use a tenant claim within each bearer token, so that when a user changes an organization on the portal (in case one user has access to several orgs), you perform relogin to the chosen tenant, or just request a new access token with a chosen tenant_id inside.

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57857527/1426685) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165743/how-do-i-customize-connect-token-to-take-custom-parameters/57167334#57167334) answers for the reference on how to pass a custom parameter (such as tenant id) with your request to Identityserver.

Comment: Thanks ! that did the job :)