# IdentityServer4 read client claims from appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

how can I read client claims from the appsettings.json file?

I have this appsettings.json:

```
"IdentityServer": {
     "Clients": [
       {
         "Enabled": true,
         "ClientId": "client1",
         "AlwaysSendClientClaims": true,
         "Claims": [
           {
             "Type": "custom_claim1",
             "Value": "value1"
           },
           {
             "Type": "custom_claim2",
             "Value": "value2"
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
}
```

And, I load the clients config [like the docs says](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html#defining-clients-in-appsettings-json):

```cs
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(opts =>
{
    /// Opts removed for simplicity
})
   .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Clients"));
```

All is working fine, except for the client claims. I can not see them in Jwt.io decode tool.

Comment: None of the examples I've seen includes `Claims` when adding in-memory clients

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in reading the client claims? It seems the actual problem is that claims do not make it to the token: _I can not see them in Jwt.io decode tool_. Which is an entirely other issue. Can you confirm that the claims are not loaded, in other words, the client has no claims?

Comment: When I configure clients in memory with code (same settings), the claims are added to the jwt. The problem is when i try to load  from the json.

Comment: There is one open issue concerning [reading clients from json](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2573), but since your application doesn't crash this may not be related to your problem.

Comment: Still, did you confirm that the claims are not loaded for the client?

Comment: Weither or not you can see client claims in the token response has nothing to do with how you load them.   Also these are client claims and not user claims i suspect that may have something to do with your problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/43894146/1841839

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem binding the Claims collection in the Clients[] from appSettings.json due to the fact that the current implementation of the Claim object can not be deserialized from json.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2573

and here

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/pull/3887/files/ed14abc204960b2d5ca3418a868882a698e54d90